# Extracting Several Tables to Excel From BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have extracted several tables from BeautifulSoup from different URL:s and I get them to print fine within python. However, when I try to extract it to excel, it doesn't work. The tables are stored in a list but I can't find a way to store them in excel.

I want every table in a different sheet but I can't print a list straight into excel and the tables.

I have a list of many url:s, but here is some of them to show how they look.

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312510083400/ddef14a.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312511098071/ddef14a.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312512157233/d293744ddef14a.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312513152959/d469796ddef14a.htm

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import xlwt

xl = pd.ExcelFile(r'/path/to/file/with/links.xlsx')
link = xl.parse('Sheet1') 

book = xlwt.Workbook()

list1 = []

for i in range(10,16):
    try:
        url = link['Link'][i]
        html = requests.get(url).content
        df_list = pd.read_html(html)

        #I have matched up two keywords
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
        table1 = soup.select_one('table:contains("Fees")')
        table2 = soup.select_one('table:contains("Earned")')
        if table1 == table2:
            df = pd.read_html(str(table1))
            list1.append(df)

#HERE BELOW IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS

            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Tables_Fees_Earned.xlsx')
            for counter in range(len(list1)):
                sheet_name = 'Sheet%s' % counter
                pd.Series(name = '').to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
                for c in range(len(list1)):
                    list1[c].to_excel(writer,'Sheet%s' % counter)

            writer.save()


        else:
            print(i)
```

The error is: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Filip! provide the url which you are scraping

Comment: Thank you! I have added some of the links now :)

Comment: I was using xlrd package for manipulating Excel files successfuly.

Comment: As Panda's documentation states, the method [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) works in DataFrames, not in Series as you are trying.

Comment: @GuilhermeFelitti Can I convert the tables into a series so I can extract it?

Comment: It's a list he is trying on and not a pandas series.@GuilhermeFelitti